# Android L CardView and RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a question about CardView and RecyclerView. Can I use these widgets in older versions of the application. For example, for my application specified limits:

```
 android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

I wanted to make a test case for android 4.2.2, but began to emerge error. So I decided to learn about supporting versions, and then I will sit to suffer for nothing

Answer (score 0):

**Can I use these widgets in older versions** :

Yes you can. Those can be supported from API level = 7.

To use this in android studio add bellow line in your app build.gradle file.

**Like :**

```
dependencies {
....
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'
```

}

Comment: And if i use Intellij IDEA without gradle?

Comment: did you use android studio? It is built on Intellij IDEA, so why do you need  Intellij IDEA without gradle. Google provided eclipse adt bundle & android studio for development. I think it is best to select from two of them.